# Trim dataframe by total of column

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say that I have a data frame with a column named `subtotal`, and I want to extract a sub-data frame with a maximum sum of all subtotal

```
l = [100, 200, 300, 400, 500]

df = pd.DataFrame(l)
```

Here, I want to get a `df` with maximum value of `1000`, in this case, should return `[100, 200, 300, 400]`

How can I do this using panda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is one way to do it

```
#take cumsum and choose only rows that are at or below the threshold

df.loc[df[0].cumsum()<=1000]
```

```
0
0   100
1   200
2   300
3   400
```